# How to select specific fields from a GET request

Tags: python, json, python-requests

In my python I have the following code that access an API:

```py
def get_letters(url):
    """
    GET letters
    """
    authHeader = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    return requests.get(url, headers=authHeader).json()

get_phone('https://letters.com/rest/v10')
```

that returns:

```
{
    'a': 'aaaaa',
    'b': 
    {
         'c': 'cccc',
         'd': 'dddd',
         'e': 'eeee',
    }
}
```

How can I specify to my GET request that I want the following output?

```
{
     'c': 'cccc',
     'd': 'dddd',
     'e': 'eeee',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided code doesn't work for me. I've got an error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 5 (char 4)`. The URL doesn't return a JSON.

Regardless, if as a result of calling `get_phone()` or `get_letters()` (please update your code) you have a dictionary, you can access 'b' object by doing:

```
res = get_phone('https://letters.com/rest/v10')
print(res['b'])
```

Where `res['b']` will contain what you need.

Although, some rest APIs let you filter the results by using URL parameters. Here are some [examples](https://jsonapi.org/examples/).

Comment: this api is an exemple, if you know any one that I can use for a better exemple, I will be thankfull

Comment: @DaniloMatrangoloMarano check out this [repo](https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis).